# Reading environment variable and executing based on condition in PHP

Tags: php, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, magento2, jenkins-groovy

Hey PHP experts out there. I have a Jenkins job which sets an environment variable called "CLEAN_INSTALL". In my deploy.php for Magento I have written code like below to conditionally execute a task based on the value of this variable. But it seems the variable is not having a value while this is run.

```
set('clean_install', checkAndGetEnv('CLEAN_INSTALL'));

task('magento:install', function() {
    if ( $clean_install == "false" ) {
        return true;
    }
    run('cd {{release_path}}');
    run('{{bin/php}} {{release_path}}/bin/magento setup:install 
});
```

The log returns error like below.
07:13:50  PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: clean_install in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/magentoy/deploy.php on line 115

What am I doing wrong here. I am not a PHP developer though.

Comment: Can you add the code of method `checkAndGetEnv` to check out what it's doing?

Comment: Ok @GerarddeVisser I think I am using the same checkAndGetEnv('CLEAN_INSTALL')